# c strcpy copy to array of string

Tags: c

```
char strarr[5][10];
```

when I use

```
strcpy(strarr[0], src);
```

try to copy contents from src to strarr[0] .I got seg fault.

Is this wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: is `src` null-terminated?  does it fit in `strarr`?

Comment: What's the value of src? Is it pointing to a string? Can you give the minimal example that shows the seg fault instead of snippets with potentially important parts missing?

Comment: Who knows? You don't seem to be learning how to post proper questions here, and until you do, I'm afraid your very poor questions will keep getting closed by people like me.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you show us more code we can only assume `src` is more than the space availabe. Also it may be that `src` is not `NUL`-terminated.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is the `src` pointer, and its length.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [strncpy()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strncpy.html).

`strncpy(dest[0], src, 10);`